# json файл возвращает null

Tags: android, json, kotlin, null

Данные из json передаются следующим образом

```
try {
        val jsonString = loadJsonFromFile(fileName, context)
        val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
        val jsonPages = json.getJSONArray("pages")

        for (index in 0 until jsonPages.length()) {
            val questionText = (index + 1).toString() + ". " + jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_QUESTION_TEXT)
            val answerOneText = jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_ANSWER_ONE)
            val answerTwoText = jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_ANSWER_TWO)
            val answerThreeText = jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_ANSWER_THREE)
            val answerFourText = jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_ANSWER_FOUR)
            val correctAnswerNumber = jsonPages.getJSONObject(index).getString(KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER)
            pages.add(QuestionAnswerPage(questionText, answerOneText, answerTwoText, answerThreeText, answerFourText, correctAnswerNumber))
        }
    } catch (e: JSONException)
```

/

```
if (args != null) {
    questionText.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_QUESTION_TEXT)
    radioOne.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_ONE)
    radioTwo.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_TWO)
    radioThree.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_THREE)
    radioFour.text = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_FOUR)
    correctAnswerNumber = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER)}
```

строка correctAnswerNumber = args.getString(PageTaker.KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER) подсвечитвается: Type mismatch. Required: String, Found: String?
Получается, что переменная correctAnswerNumber будет null, хотя с остальными переменными, которым передаются значения из json файла, такого не происходит. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Сам json файл

```
{"pages":[{
  "questionText":"Что такое преобразователь частоты?",
  "answerOne": "Электротехническое устройство, предназначенное для преобразования электроэнергии промышленной амплитуды и частоты в электроэнергию с регулируемой амплитудой и частотой",
  "answerTwo": "что-то",
  "answerThree": "То же самое, что тиристорный преобразователь напряжения",
  "answerFour": "ничего",
  "correctAnswer": "1"},
{"questionText": "Вопрос 2",
  "answerOne": "Неправильный ответ 1 (2)",
  "answerTwo": "Неправильный ответ 2 (2)",
  "answerThree": "Правильный ответ (2)",
  "answerFour": "Неправильный ответ 3 (2)",
  "correctAnswer": "3"},
{"questionText":"Вопрос 3",
  "answerOne": "Неправильный ответ 1 (3)",
  "answerTwo": "Неправильный ответ 2 (3)",
  "answerThree": "Правильный ответ (3)",
  "answerFour": "Неправильный ответ 3 (3)",
  "correctAnswer": "3"}]}
```

Пробовал делать correctAnswer целочисленным, результат тот же.

newInstance():

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(questionAnswerPage: QuestionAnswerPage): PageFragment  {

        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_QUESTION_TEXT, questionAnswerPage.questionText)
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_ONE, questionAnswerPage.answerOne)
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_TWO, questionAnswerPage.answerTwo)
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_THREE, questionAnswerPage.answerThree)
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_ANSWER_FOUR, questionAnswerPage.answerFour)
        args.putString(PageTaker.KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER, questionAnswerPage.correctAnswer)

        val fragment = PageFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment

    }
}
```

Comment: Обновил свой ответ, загляните)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `newInstance` Вы кладете

```
args.putInt(PageTaker.KEY_CORRECT_ANSWER, questionAnswerPage.correctAnswer)
```

А нужно `putString`, раз уж у Вас `String`. Код смотрел в другом Вашем вопросе, добавьте в этот вопрос `newInstance`, пожалуйста.
  P.s. Для того, чтобы показывать результат всех вопросов, Вам нужно их учитывать в коде. Я это вижу примерно так:

В `activity`:

```
const val APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings"
const val APP_PREFS_SCORE = "my_settings_score"
private lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences 

....

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    .....
}

fun changeScore(addition: Int){
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    val oldValue = prefs.getInt(APP_PREFS_SCORE, 0) ?: 0
    val newValue = if(oldValue + addition < 0) 0
    else oldValue + addition
    editor.putInt(APP_PREFS_SCORE, newValue)
    editor.apply()
}

fun getScore(): Int {
    return prefs.getInt(APP_PREFS_SCORE, 0) ?: 0
}
```

И во фрагменте:

```
val myActivity = requireActivity() as MyActivity //тут имя Вашего класса Activity
var score = 0
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        when (isChecked) {
            R.id.radio_one-> when {
                correctAnswerNumber == "1" -> myActivity.changeScore(1)
            }
            R.id.radio_two -> when {
                correctAnswerNumber == "2" -> myActivity.changeScore(1)
            }
            R.id.radio_three -> when {
                correctAnswerNumber == "3" -> myActivity.changeScore(1)
            }
            R.id.radio_four -> when {
                correctAnswerNumber == "4" -> myActivity.changeScore(1)
            }
            else -> myActivity.changeScore(-1)
        }
    }
```

То есть общий счет будет сохраняться в файле настроек. Решение не самое хорошее, но простое. Для обучения - вполне сойдет.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Все работает. С обнулением счетчика разобрался так:
finishButton.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, mainActivity.getScore().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                mainActivity.changeScore(-1 * mainActivity.getScore())
            }

Comment: @Larian Если ответ помог - отметьте его принятым, ожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Простите мою невнимательность. Поправил newInstance.

Теперь переменная score работает почти как надо.

```
var score = 0
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            when (isChecked) {
                R.id.radio_one-> when {
                    correctAnswerNumber == "1" -> score++
                }
                R.id.radio_two -> when {
                    correctAnswerNumber == "2" -> score++
                }
                R.id.radio_three -> when {
                    correctAnswerNumber == "3" -> score ++
                }
                R.id.radio_four -> when {
                    correctAnswerNumber == "4" -> score++
                }
                else -> when {
                    score < 1 -> score = 0
                    else -> score--
                }
            }
        }
```

Результат score отображается всегда для одного фрагмента. Не подскажите, как это дело поправить, чтобы выводился суммарный результат всех фрагментов? Сделать кнопку и score за рамками класса PageFragment?